# What would the effect of the Happily Ever After potion have been on Fiona?

Tags: shrek

In *Shrek* (the first film of the *Shrek* franchise), an alternate opening was story boarded but never filmed, called ["Fiona's Prologue"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Hy8Uqy_T4Q).

In it, Fiona was born an ogre, which was why she was locked in the tower. She goes to a fortune teller (who was the inspiration for Fairy Godmother) for help. She gives Fiona a choice between a beauty potion or a happily ever after potion. She drank the beauty one, which gave her the same curse she had in the actual film — human by day, ogre by night.

But what would've happened if she had drank the happily ever after potion? Would it have the same effect as it did in *Shrek 2*: turned you beautiful and you have to kiss your true love prior to midnight to make the effects permanent?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**We do not know.**

The alternate opening never made it into the film, and we don't know if the potion to live happily ever after we see in the story board, was envisioned to be even *remotely* the same to that in *Shrek 2* — a film that hadn't even been scripted then.

Comment: Is there a reason you made this a CW answer?

Comment: @Valorum because I wanted to disown the answer just saying "we don't know".

Comment: @Valorum and anyone with the same questioning: [related chat transcript](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/46266076#46266076)

Comment: That's not what CW is for.

Comment: @Valorum actually, yes. CW _is_ for disowning an answer.

Comment: @SQB - It's for disowning it **in the expectation that others will contribute significantly**; https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10101/what-are-the-guidelines-for-marking-an-answer-as-community-wiki

Answer (score 2):

It's likely it would have turned her back into her human self.

1. At the end of *Shrek 1*, after Shrek kisses her, Fiona undergoes a "magic moment" in which the curse is undone and Fiona is astonished that she is now an ogre (not "beautiful" according to her). She clearly thought of herself as human in some respect at that point.
2. Shrek had changed into a human after drinking the potion which *also turned Fiona back into a human*. The potion clearly made you beautiful by the standards of others.
3. It's unlikely the Fairy Godmother would make a potion that would turn you into *your* definition of beauty. Remember, she's running a business. Customers would be angry paying for a potion that didn't make them beautiful in the eyes of others.

Comment: What do u mean "in the same way?"

Comment: In the same way Shrek drinking the potion made both he and Fiona human, it's likely she would have turned back into her human self and Shrek into a human man.

Comment: But it wouldn’t have turned her “BACK into her human self.” She was BORN an ogre in this alternate opening. Becoming beautiful was why she went to the fortune teller. And remember, this is an alternate opening, not Shrek 2.